Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' in Node.js
I am currently a React and Node.js app. Before writing the MariaDB API I need to ensure connection with the database, everyhting was working properly, but now I get this error:
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/mariadb/lib/pool-promise.js 14:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (14:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const Errors = require('./misc/errors');
| class PoolPromise extends EventEmitter {
>   #pool;
|   constructor(options) {
|     super();


This is the file in question:
//  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later
//  Copyright (c) 2015-2024 MariaDB Corporation Ab

'use strict';

const { EventEmitter } = require('events');

const Pool = require('./pool');
const ConnectionPromise = require('./connection-promise');
const CommandParameter = require('./command-parameter');
const Errors = require('./misc/errors');

class PoolPromise extends EventEmitter {
  #pool;
  constructor(options) {
    super();
    this.#pool = new Pool(options);
    this.#pool.on('acquire', this.emit.bind(this, 'acquire'));
    this.#pool.on('connection', this.emit.bind(this, 'connection'));
    this.#pool.on('enqueue', this.emit.bind(this, 'enqueue'));
    this.#pool.on('release', this.emit.bind(this, 'release'));
    this.#pool.on('error', this.emit.bind(this, 'error'));
  }

  get closed() {
    return this.#pool.closed;
  }

  /**
   * Get current total connection number.
   * @return {number}
   */
  totalConnections() {
    return this.#pool.totalConnections();
  }

  /**
   * Get current active connections.
   * @return {number}
   */
  activeConnections() {
    return this.#pool.activeConnections();
  }

  /**
   * Get current idle connection number.
   * @return {number}
   */
  idleConnections() {
    return this.#pool.idleConnections();
  }

  /**
   * Get current stacked connection request.
   * @return {number}
   */
  taskQueueSize() {
    return this.#pool.taskQueueSize();
  }

  escape(value) {
    return this.#pool.escape(value);
  }

  escapeId(value) {
    return this.#pool.escapeId(value);
  }

  /**
   * Ends pool
   *
   * @return Promise
   **/
  end() {
    return this.#pool.end();
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve a connection from pool.
   * Create a new one, if limit is not reached.
   * wait until acquireTimeout.
   *
   */
  async getConnection() {
    const cmdParam = new CommandParameter();
    if (this.#pool.opts.connOptions.trace) Error.captureStackTrace(cmdParam);
    const baseConn = await this.#pool.getConnection(cmdParam);
    const conn = new ConnectionPromise(baseConn);
    conn.release = () => new Promise(baseConn.release);
    conn.end = conn.release;
    conn.close = conn.release;
    return conn;
  }

  /**
   * Execute query using text protocol with callback emit columns/data/end/error
   * events to permit streaming big result-set
   *
   * @param sql     sql parameter Object can be used to supersede default option.
   *                Object must then have sql property.
   * @param values  object / array of placeholder values (not mandatory)
   */
  query(sql, values) {
    const cmdParam = ConnectionPromise._PARAM(this.pool.opts.connOptions, sql, values);
    return this.pool.getConnection(cmdParam).then((baseConn) => {
      return new Promise(baseConn.query.bind(baseConn, cmdParam)).finally(() => {
        this.pool.release(baseConn);
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Execute query using binary protocol with callback emit columns/data/end/error
   * events to permit streaming big result-set
   *
   * @param sql     sql parameter Object can be used to supersede default option.
   *                Object must then have sql property.
   * @param values  object / array of placeholder values (not mandatory)
   */
  execute(sql, values) {
    const cmdParam = ConnectionPromise._PARAM(this.pool.opts.connOptions, sql, values);
    return this.pool.getConnection(cmdParam).then((baseConn) => {
      return ConnectionPromise._EXECUTE_CMD(baseConn, cmdParam).finally(() => {
        this.pool.release(baseConn);
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * execute a batch
   *
   * @param sql     sql parameter Object can be used to supersede default option.
   *                Object must then have sql property.
   * @param values  array of placeholder values
   */
  batch(sql, values) {
    const cmdParam = ConnectionPromise._PARAM(this.pool.opts.connOptions, sql, values);
    return this.pool.getConnection(cmdParam).then((baseConn) => {
      return ConnectionPromise._BATCH_CMD(baseConn, cmdParam).finally(() => {
        this.pool.release(baseConn);
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Import sql file.
   *
   * @param opts JSON array with 2 possible fields: file and database
   */
  importFile(opts) {
    if (!opts) {
      return Promise.reject(
        Errors.createError(
          'SQL file parameter is mandatory',
          Errors.ER_MISSING_SQL_PARAMETER,
          null,
          'HY000',
          null,
          false,
          null
        )
      );
    }

    return this.pool.getConnection({}).then((baseConn) => {
      return new Promise(baseConn.importFile.bind(baseConn, { file: opts.file, database: opts.database })).finally(
        () => {
          this.pool.release(baseConn);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}

module.exports = PoolPromise;


This is the mariadb module package.json
{
  "name": "mariadb",
  "version": "3.3.0",
  "description": "fast mariadb or mysql connector.",
  "main": "promise.js",
  "types": "types/index.d.ts",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test:types-prettier && npm run test:prettier && npm run test:types && npm run test:lint && npm run test:base",
    "test:base": "mocha --no-parallel --timeout 5000 \"test/**/*.js\" ",
    "test:lint": "eslint \"*.js\" \"{lib,test}/**/*.js\" ",
    "test:types": "eslint \"types/*.ts\" ",
    "test:types-prettier": "prettier --write \"types/*.ts\"",
    "test:prettier": "prettier --write \"*.js\" \"{tools,lib,test,benchmarks}/**/*.js\"",
    "coverage": "npm run coverage:test && npm run coverage:create && npm run coverage:send",
    "coverage:test": "nyc mocha --no-parallel --timeout 5000 \"test/**/*.js\"",
    "coverage:report": "npm run coverage:create && npm run coverage:send",
    "coverage:create": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov > coverage.lcov",
    "coverage:send": "./codecov --disable=gcov",
    "benchmark": "node benchmarks/benchmarks-all.js",
    "generate": "node ./tools/generate-mariadb.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "mariadb",
    "mysql",
    "client",
    "driver",
    "connector"
  ],
  "files": [
    "lib",
    "types/index.d.ts",
    "promise.js",
    "check-node.js",
    "callback.js"
  ],
  "author": "Diego Dupin <diego.dupin@mariadb.com>",
  "license": "LGPL-2.1-or-later",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.14",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.17",
    "denque": "^2.1.0",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.6.3",
    "lru-cache": "^10.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.6.0",
    "benchmark": "^2.1.4",
    "chai": "^4.4.1",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "error-stack-parser": "^2.1.4",
    "eslint": "^8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-markdown": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "mocha-lcov-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "winston": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://jira.mariadb.org/projects/CONJS/"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs#readme"
}


And this is the API I wrote, inspired from the offical MariaDB tutorials:
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

async function connectAndExecute(query){
    let conn;

    try {
        // connection with pipeline
        conn = await mariadb.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "root",
            password: "not the actual password",
            database: "spotiforums_db",
            pipeline: "true"
        });

        const users = [
            ["username1", "password1"],
            ["username2", "password2"]
        ];

        const update = {
            user: "username1",
            password: "password3"
        };

        const del = {
            user: "username2"
        };
        // performing a CRUD test
        const resolve = await crudPipeline(conn, users, update, del);
        // if successful, execute the query
        if (resolve === 1) {
            await conn.query(query);
        }

    } catch(err) {
        console.error("Error connecting to the database with pipeline: ", err);
    } finally {
        if (conn) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

    return Promise.resolve(1);
}

async function crudPipeline(conn, data, update, del) {
    try {
        await conn.beginTransaction();

        try {
            // deleting test table
            await conn.query("drop table if exists test.users");
            // creating test table
            await conn.query("create table test.users (user varchar(255) primary key not null , password VARCHAR(255) not null)");
            // inserting into test table
            await conn.batch("insert into test.users(user, password) values(?, ?)", data);
            // updating test table
            await conn.query("update test.users set password = ? where user = ?",
                [update.password, update.user]);
            // deleting from test table
            await conn.query("delete from test.users where user = ?", [del.user]);
            // reading from test table
            await conn.query("select user, password from test.users");

        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error adding user, reverting changes: ", err);
            await conn.rollback();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error starting a transaction: ", err);
    }
    // CRUD passed
    return Promise.resolve(1);
}

export default connectAndExecute;

I tried using npm audit fix --force but it just doesn't work for me, instead I wold get something like this:
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/execute-stream.js 9:4-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd'
Did you mean './stream'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/caching-sha2-password-auth.js 5:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/ed25519-password-auth.js 7:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/handshake.js 11:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/handshake.js 13:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/native-password-auth.js 7:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/sha256-password-auth.js 5:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/sha256-password-auth.js 6:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/authentication.js 13:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd\handshake'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/parser.js 10:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/query.js 12:4-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd'
Did you mean './stream'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/stream.js 9:4-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\cmd'
Did you mean './stream'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection.js 8:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection.js 15:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/connection.js 38:19-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/io/compression-input-stream.js 6:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\io'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/io/compression-output-stream.js 7:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\mariadb\lib\io'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 3:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/safer-buffer/safer.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'D:\Ale lui Vlad\Projects\SpotiForums\spotiforums\node_modules\safer-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

I always try to run npm audit fix --force or anyhting npm suggests but it doesn't work. I even tried to install browserify, still nothing.

This would seem that private field are not supported. Connector would have thrown an error if you use a node.js version < 14, and node.js support private field since v12. So you probably use some compiling framework not compatible with private field, you need to check in that direction
